# Guidelines for returning None vs. raising Error for Python string-validating functions

Tags: python, regular-expressions, validation

Let's say we have a function that checks if a given pattern occurs in a string. The default behaviour is that if the pattern matches, then it returns the pattern. So far so good but what is the recommended way to handle the case where the pattern doesn't match. There are many alternatives of course but I can list two:

- Return `None` and then handle the `None` from the calling environment
- Raise (or throw) an `Error` (let's say `NoParagraphNumberError`) and handle the error from the calling environment.

In the following code, I return `None` but is it preferable to throw an `Error`, e.g. because it will increase readability, maintainability of the code or for any other reason?

```
import re

BASIC_CASE_PATTERN = r'\d{1,6}/\d+'
BASIC_PARAGRAPH_PATTERN = ur'(paras?(\W|\s)|paragraphs?)'


def check_case_citation(citation_string):
    """
    Check the citation string for occurence of patterns
    Returns:
        str: if just a case number is found
        None: if no case number is found or the citation includes paragraph numbers
    """
    paragraph = re.compile(BASIC_PARAGRAPH_PATTERN)
    casepattern = re.compile(BASIC_CASE_PATTERN)

    match = re.search(casepattern, citation_string)

    #1. entries with case number(s) but no paragraph given
    if match and re.search(paragraph, citation_string) is None:
        return match.group()
    else:
        return None


print check_case_citation("Case 145/80") # 145/80
print check_case_citation("Case 145/80 paragraph 3") # None
```

Comment: Migrated from Code Review because the question is about best practices in general rather than improving the code excerpt.

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely go for the `return None` option. Raising an exception may increase readability (although I doubt it) on the function itself, but handling it is messier. If you `return None`, from the caller function you can do the following:

```
citation = check_case_citation("Case 145/80")
if citation:
   # Do something
else:
   # Do something else
```

while, if you raise an exception, you would have something like

```
try:
   citation = check_case_citation("Case 145/80")
   # Do something
except NoParagraphNumberError:
   # Do something else
```

The third option, as suggested by Mathias Ettinger, would be to do

```
try:
   citation = check_case_citation("Case 145/80")
except NoParagraphNumberError:
   # Do something else
else:
   # Do something
```

I don't know about you, but to me the first alternative looks the cleanest and most straightforward...

Comment: In the case of the exception, I would definitely use the `else` clause of the `try` to *do something* and use a custom exception instead of the most generic one: `try: citation = check_case_citation('Case 145/80'); except CheckException: do_handle_bad_case(); else: do_handle(citation);`

Comment: @eSedano Thanks for your answer. Please see my edits. You are right about the `Exception` per se but I wanted to say `Error` instead, it is just that my Java past is haunting me :). So do you think your answer changes if we raise an Error?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger do you mean `except` clause instead of `else`?

Comment: @YannisP. No, I mean `else`. As in [`try .. except .. else .. finally`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/855759/5069029).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I have never come across this idiom. Strange logic but thanks for sharing. I wish I could upvote!

Comment: @YannisP As far as I know, there is no real distinction between `Error` and `Exception` in Python... All the `FooBarError` are, in fact, exceptions. So it doesn't change my reply :)

And yes, the `try .. except .. else` is a powerful construct, but it still would leave the code a bit more confusing than the necessary for no special reason.

Comment: It depend on the meaning, namely the `int` function or the likes expect an `try .. except .. else` construct. But I’m with you about the fact that a "check" is better when returning a boolean. Although, in this case, "check" is not a great name since it change the input to something else, pretty much like `int` does… However, my initial comment was more to *just* expand the answer with the use of the `else` clause and the change from a generic exception to a specialized one.

Comment: `try ... except ... else` is by far the best solution for Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the second option, raising an error and then handle it in the calling environment with the `try-except` construct. I say this because in contrast to other programming languages like C, in Python the **EAFP** (*it’s easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*) approach is the idiomatic way of writing Python code.
As Brett Canon explains in this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/) *"you should just do what you expect to work and if an exception might be thrown from the operation then catch it and deal with that fact"*.